# How to remove CSS and JS source mapping instructions

Tags: symfony, twig, source-maps, metronic

We bought Metronic admin theme but when I use  Metronic assets (js, css, plugins etc...) into my Symfony project and I start my symfony server, I got multiple exceptions with the same problem :

`Exception : No route found for "GET /assets/plugins/custom/flot/dist/es5/jquery.flot.js.map"`

Every files which have `//# sourceMappingURL=jquery.flot.js.map` generate this exception

So, the problem seems to be my project trying to find files with .map extension but I don't have them.

I tried to delete the line with `sourceMappingUrl` but this isn't works, I have always this exception.

I don't want to use webpack-encore and I call my js or css like this :

```css
<script src="{{ asset('assets/plugins/custom/flot/dist/es5/jquery.flot.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How can I solve this issue ? Thanks for helping !